# Discord Bot Task Not Updating

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a group of voice channels on the discord server that display stats, but my task isn't updating for some reason. Not sure why. It will create the channels if none exists, but it won't update them if they already exist.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = 30)
async def serverstats():
    guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds)
    total_channels = len(guild.text_channels) + len(guild.voice_channels)
    list_channels = []
    perms = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect = False, view_channel = True)
    }

    for channel in guild.channels:
        list_channels.append(channel.name)

    if 'Server Stats' not in list_channels:
        stat_category = await guild.create_category('Server Stats')
        stat_memb_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Users: {len(guild.members)} ', overwrites=perms, category = stat_category)
        stat_role_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Roles: {len(guild.roles)} ', overwrites=perms, category = stat_category)
        stat_voice_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Channels: {total_channels} ', overwrites=perms, category = stat_category)
    if 'Server Stats' in list_channels:
        await stat_memb_channel.edit(name = f'Users: {len(guild.members)}')
        await stat_role_channel.edit(name = f'Roles: {len(guild.roles)}')
        await stat_voice_channel.edit(name = f'Channels: {total_channels} ')
```

Upon further investigation, removing the bottom for loop fixes the bot stopping the task loop, but does not solve my problem.

EDIT: This is the cleaned up code from the author who typed the solution. There were a few syntax errors, but the general idea of the code was all correct.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = 15)
async def serverstats():
    guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds)
    stat_memb_channel = None
    stat_role_channel = None
    stat_voice_channel = None
    stat_category = None
    bot_channel = None
    perms = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect = False, view_channel = True)
    }

    for channel in guild.channels:
        if channel.name.startswith('Server Stats'):
            stat_category = channel
        if channel.name.startswith('Users: '):
            stat_memb_channel = channel
        if channel.name.startswith('Roles: '):
            stat_role_channel = channel
        if channel.name.startswith('Channels: '):
            stat_voice_channel = channel
        if channel.name.startswith('Bots: '):
            bot_channel = channel
```

```
    Bots = 0
    for member in guild.members:
        for role in member.roles:
            if role.name == 'Bot':
                Bots += 1


    if stat_category is None:
        stat_category = await guild.create_category('Server Stats')
    if bot_channel is None:
        bot_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Bots: {Bots} ', overwrites=perms, category = stat_category)
    else:
        await bot_channel.edit(name = f'Bots: {Bots}')
    if stat_memb_channel is None:
        stat_memb_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Users: {len(guild.members)} ', overwrites=perms, category = stat_category)
    else:
        await stat_memb_channel.edit(name = f'Users: {len(guild.members)}')
    if stat_role_channel is None:
        stat_role_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Roles: {len(guild.roles)} ', overwrites=perms, category = stat_category)
    else:
        await stat_role_channel.edit(name = f'Roles: {len(guild.roles)}')
    if stat_voice_channel is None:
        total_channels = len(guild.text_channels) + len(guild.voice_channels) 
        stat_voice_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Channels: {total_channels} ', overwrites=perms, category = stat_category)
    else:
        total_channels = len(guild.text_channels) + len(guild.voice_channels) 
        await stat_voice_channel.edit(name = f'Channels: {total_channels - 4} ')
```

Comment: If `Server Stats` already exits, then `stat_memb_channel` and the other channel variables are never defined.  You should add an `else` clause to the first `for` loop to get those channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = 30)
async def serverstats():
    guild = discord.utils.get(bot.guilds)
    stat_memb_channel = None
    stat_role_channel = None
    stat_voice_channel = None
    stat_category = None
    perms = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(connect = False, view_channel = True)
    }

    for channel in guild.channels:
        if channel.name.startswith('Server Stats'):
            stat_category = channel
        if channel.name.startswith('Users: '):
            stat_memb_channel = channel
        if channel.name.startswith('Roles: '):
            stat_roles_channel = channel
        if channel.name.startswith('Channels: '):
            stat_voice_channel = channel

    if stat_category is None:
        stat_category = await guild.create_category('Server Stats')
    if stat_memb_channel is None:
        stat_memb_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Users: {len(guild.members)} ', overwrites=perms, category = stat_category)
    else:
        await stat_memb_channel.edit(name = f'Users: {len(guild.members)}')
    if stat_role_channel is None:
        stat_role_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Roles: {len(guild.roles)} ', overwrites=perms, category = stat_category)
    else:
        await stat_role_channel.edit(name = f'Roles: {len(guild.roles)}')
    if stat_voice_channel is None:
        total_channels = len(guild.text_channels) + len(guild.voice_channels) + 1
        stat_voice_channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(f'Channels: {total_channels} ', overwrites=perms, category = stat_category)
    else:
        await stat_voice_channel.edit(name = f'Channels: {total_channels} ')
```